# How to make paramiko wait for transfer to finish?

Tags: python

I've tried various ways to upload a file locally to a FTP, ncftpput was really slow compared to lftp so I switched.

but what I've noticed is my python script waits for ncftpput to finish but when using lftp, it just uploads the file to the FTP and it continues on with the script..

I am using paramiko to SSH into my web server and uploading a file to another FTP.

Is there any way to make it 'wait'? I dont want to use sleep because file sizes are going to vary and its either waiting too long for a small file or not waiting long enough for a big file.

Any ideas? or alternatives to lftp/ncftpput?

Answer (score -1):

See the [lftp docs](http://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html) for proper usage of the ftp:sync-mode setting. (You want `true`.)

Comment: hmm i've tried to edit the lftp.conf file to true and on, both dont seem to make a difference

Comment: Are you sure you edited the right file? The one on the remote host?